# Why does my gem list show a gem in my gem list but doesn't let me uninstall it in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Currently in my console I type `gem list` and it shows two versions of the `diff-lcs` gem:
`diff-lcs (1.1.3, 1.1.2)`

When I run `gem uninstall diff-lcs` I get the following error:
`INFO:  gem "diff-lcs" is not installed`

I'm current running RVM. When I run `rvm current` I get:
`ruby-1.9.2-p290`

Why is this happening?  Shouldn't I be able to uninstall it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RVM uses a global gemset and I've seen a similar behavior before when trying to uninstall gems from it. You might be able to uninstall this gem by changing to that gemset and then uninstalling them:

```
rvm gemset use global
gem uninstall diff-lcs
```